# HttpWebRequest the underlying connection was closed

Tags: c#, post, httpwebrequest

I am using `HttpWebRequest` to `POST` a byte array picture through web services, the picture size is something like `byte[4096]`

Code:

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(wsHost);
webRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip,deflate");
webRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.KeepAlive, "true");
```

I get an error:

```
The underlying connection was closed. A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server
```

Is it the server problem, or my posting problem?

Comment: ..and what happens when you set `webRequest.KeepAlive = false;` ?

Comment: I change it to false. the error still same. The thing is the post is not log in Fiddler.

Comment: I assume you've debugged and found that `wsHost` is actually a valid URL you're posting to?

Comment: It is the fiddler proxy problem, it close the connection. How do I enable it to support bigger data post?

Comment: Are you using and older version of Fiddler? Someone is describing similar problems here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/httpfiddler/0-Ew7uRVDFc

Answer (score 6):

It could be a large number of things. Can you connect to the server otherwise?

If so, try turning off Expected 100 Continue (before you make your POST) via

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
```

> According to the HTTP 1.1 protocol, when this header is sent, the form data is not sent with the initial request. Instead, this header is sent to the web server which responds with 100 (Continue) if implemented correctly. However, not all web servers handle this correctly, including the server to which I am attempting to post data.

via http://haacked.com/archive/2004/05/15/http-web-request-expect-100-continue.aspx

If that doesn't work another resource: http://geekswithblogs.net/Denis/archive/2005/08/16/50365.aspx suggests that many have solved by crafting their requests as HTTP 1.0 requests:

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(wsHost);
webRequest.KeepAlive = false;
webRequest.ProtocolVersion=HttpVersion.Version10;
```

Comment: Yes I have it turn off. This only happen when the byte array is big.

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your initial post with all the different things you've tried? This problem happens for a bunch of different reasons and I would hope not to keep suggesting things you've already tried.

Comment: I am using fiddler, it closes the connection.

Comment: I can set the KeepAlive property on my Wcf service client but how do I set the protocol version?

Comment: BTW.  My client application works fine on other machines. It does not work on my box, which means I can't debug other issues.  It seems to have stopped working after running about a years worth of windows updates on a windows 7 box.

Comment: Still not working, I'm trying to user Proxy so because of that I get this error. If I remove Proxy part of the code than works again. Hovewer I want to set proxy otherwise others on other side of the wire are blocking my request :)